# USB KVM switch controlled with Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, usb, hardware, gpio, switching

I need to control 1 USB port with Raspberry pi and as I understand I need this relay:

https://static.chipdip.ru/lib/128/DOC004128221.pdf

Does it switch with GPIO? And will this work?

Comment: I don't understand what you meant under *control USB port*, but if you need to cut signals, you better search for USB cutter.

Comment: @0andriy Like i have 3 usb ports - 2 output, 1 input. 1 connected to e.g. PC, 2 others - usb devices. And with raspberry pi I need to switch between them.

Comment: For example, https://www.cleware-shop.de/USB-Cutter/en